# Что такое pair и где использовать?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять зачем такое объединение двух объектов разного или одного типа, в один объект?
И чем это отличается от map?
И как или какой смысл использовать pair вместе с map?

Comment: Может хотя бы потому что пара быстрее и дает больше возможностей для структурирования кода..

Answer (score 8):

Ну, мало ли зачем может понадобиться. Например, для того же `std::map`: когда итерируете по нему, *текущим* элементом является пара из ключа и значения, то есть соответственно `std::pair<K, V>`.

Ещё при помощи пары легко моделировать функцию, которая может вернуть, а может и не вернуть значение.

Пример:

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<bool, T> parse_string(const std::wstring &s)
{
    std::wistringstream iss(s);
    T t;
    bool success = !(iss >> t).fail();
    return std::make_pair(success, t);
}

auto r1 = parse_string<int>(L"123");
if (r1.first)
    cout << r.second;
else
    cout << "fail";
```

Или, например, функция двоичного поиска в отсортированном массиве. По-хорошему она должна возвращать не *какой-то* из найденных индексов, в *все* индексы, потому что элементы могут повторяться. Впрочем, такая функцию уже есть: [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) возвращает именно `std::pair` из начального и конечного итераторов.

Функция целочисленного деления тоже по-хорошему должна возвращать пару из частного и остатка.

Для всех этих случаев заводить специальные структуры данных означало бы излишнюю захламлённость кода, и необходимость держать в голове десятки специальных типов данных, которые есть по существу не больше, чем пара объектов. C++ достаточно сложен и без этого.

Comment: Еще кстати работа с std::multimap основана на std::pair.

std::multimap<int , int> M;
M.insert(std::pair<int , int>(5,2));

Answer (score 4):

std::map это контейнер, он эффективен только для достаточно большого количества данных  ~ > 100. Использовать его для 1-2 значений не очень разумно.

Применение:

- Хранить 2D клетку карты.
- Хранить Координаты X и Y.
- Хранить тип переменной для void*.
- Если нужен индекс по двойному ключу. (имя-фамилия)

  ```
  std::map<std::string , std::map<std::string,досье>> персонал;
  персонал["Эл"]["Якобсон"].зарплата = 500000;

  //в данном случаи поиск ключа будет выполнятся 1 раз, что может положительно сказаться на производительности
  std::map<std::pair<std::string,std::string>,досье> персонал;
  персонал[std::pair<std::string,std::string>("Эл","Якобсон")].зарплата = 500000;
  ```
- Вспомогательная переменная для определения действий(в дополнение к ответу VladD).

> enum АВТОМОЙКА { ЛЕГКОВАЯ, ГРУЗОВАЯ,
> ГУМАНОИД };

```
std::pair<ТИП_ОБРАБОТКИ,std::string> объект = текущий_объект_на_ленте();
if(объект.first == ЛЕГКОВАЯ){ загрузить_программу_легковой(объект.second);}
if(объект.first == ГРУЗОВАЯ){ загрузить_программу_грузовой(объект.second);}
if(объект.first == ГУМАНОИД){ остановить_чистку(); удалить_объект(объект.second);}
```

---

Преимущества:

**сравнение**:

```
// для одиночных переменных
int X1;
int Y1;
int X2;
int Y2;

if(X1 == X2 && Y1 == Y2){} // выглядит не очень

// для pair
typedef std::pair<int , int> клетка;
клетка клетка_1;
клетка клетка_2;

if(клетка_1 == клетка_2){} // так более понятно
```

**Компактность**:

Если две переменные логически связаны, то создавать для этой связи новый тип(struct) слишком затратно.

```
struct товар
{
int ид;
std::string название;
operator==()
operator!=()
конструктор()
};

проще:
std::pair<int , std::string> товар;
```

**Скорость**:

```
std::pair<int , std::string> товар;
auto ид_товара = товар.ид; // доступ сразу

std::map<int , std::string> товар2;
auto ид_товара = товар2.begin()->first; // доступ через итератор
```

**Память**:

> std::map выделяет память под разные
> внутренние конструкции(вспомогательные переменные)(это же к/ч
> дерево(или не совсем к/ч)). В debug
> режиме заметно снижает
> производительность и затрудняет
> отладку.

Тип пара, по идее имеет только два члена. И память выделяется только под них.

Например:

```
template<typename first_ , typename second_>
struct pair
{
first_ first;
second_ second;
};
```

---

Недостатки:

**Рефакторинг будет затруднён**:

Если вместо X,Y окажется что необходимо работать с X,Y,Z то будет не очень приятно.
Придется писать свой тип *трира*. уже с 3 элементами или делать struct.

В то время как используя struct достаточно просто добавить int Z; и обновить методы этой структуры.

Comment: ну, если намечается увеличение количества элементов, стоит посмотреть в сторону [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: std::pair<int , std::string> пара;
    функция( пара.first , пара.second);
    
    // Заменяется на
    enum{first_=0 , second_=1,third_=2}
    std::tuple<int , std::string , char> трира;
    функция( std::get<first_>(трира) , std::get<second_>(трира) , std::get<third_>(трира));

То есть повозится придётся везде, где идут вызовы.
А при структуре изменяется в основном только в .h и .cpp где определена.

Поэтому мне кажется это всё таки недостаток такой формы при сравнении со структурой.

Comment: >> Вспомогательная переменная для определения действий(в дополнение к ответу VladD).

Так лучше не делать. Используйте полиморфизм на виртуальных функциях.

Comment: @atwice 
Ну да. Только здесь показан один из вариантов использования std::pair.
И мне кажется в определенных областях(прикладных) проще записать алгоритмические функции в си стиле, а не делать классы.  Но это всё так сказать спорно.

... 
Хотя наверное лучше сразу прививать ооп, а не путать, задающего вопрос, разными стилями.